# Htaccess - redirect 'file' from not existing directory

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect not existing files to index.php in my root directory, and I have this rule in my htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

This redirects me **http://www.test.de/test.php** to index.php properly.

But **http://www.test.de/test/test.php** does not work. Can I redirect files from not existing diretories?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, you can.
you can test this one:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [L]
```